# Can't add comma to sql text

Tags: mysql, sql, string-concatenation

Why doesn't this statement work?

```
UPDATE users 
   SET downloaded = downloaded + "4,";
```

It will only set downloaded equal to 4. downloaded is of type text. What am i doing wrong? I'm using mysql.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: Some databases doesn't use `+` for concatenating strings. Some databases doesn't use quotation marks as string delimiters. What database are you using?

Comment: The ANSI means of concatenating strings is to use the double pipe: ||.  IE: `downloaded || '4, '`.   But to my knowledge, only PostgreSQL and Oracle support it natively.  MySQL might if you turn on ANSI support, dunno about DB2.

Comment: @OMGPonies: SQLite also understands `||`; MySQL will understand `||` for string concatenation if you `set sql_mode = 'ansi'` (which I don't think anyone actually does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MySQL at least, if you want string concatenation, try this instead:

```
UPDATE users SET downloaded = CONCAT(downloaded, '4,');
```

I think that by using the addition operator you are parsing the string as numeric, giving you only `4`.

Comment: Also depending on the RDBMS you may need to use single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the CONCAT function.

Comment: Not every database has a CONCAT function

Comment: Good Point,  If you are using Mysql then you CONCAT.